# MS Access query time field, determine if time falls between a range

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-office

Just building a simple Query in Access and ran into a problem.

if the Criteria is Between #8:00:00 PM# And #1:00:00 AM# I would expect only 5 hours evaluated, but that doesn't happen. It returns values that happened at 8:00 AM 9:00 AM and so on.

I just want to the results to be between a certain time for 1 day, I realize that the day changes at 00:00: but there are a few times where for a work day this time falls over the Midnight timeline.

I realize that the expression is probably doing exactly what it is supposed to, but don't know how to enter an expression that fits my needs.

```
The SQL is: SELECT HealthVault2.Time, HealthVault2.Date_Time
FROM HealthVault2
WHERE (((HealthVault2.Time) Between #12/30/1899 20:0:0# And #12/30/1899 1:0:0#));
```

I have no idea where the 12/30/1899 is coming from, there is only a time in that field (when I hit F2, or click in the field, there isn't a datetime value)

I am sure I am overlooking something simple.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All date values are numbers. There is no such thing as a time without a date, time is the fraction.

Comment: what values you have in HealthVault2.Date_Time field

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    HealthVault2.Time, HealthVault2.Date_Time
FROM 
    HealthVault2
WHERE 
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) Between #00:00:00# And #20:00:00#;
```

For 20:00 to 01:00 (next day):

```
WHERE 
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) >= #20:00:00#
    OR
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) <= #01:00:00#;
```

For StartTime to EndTime (could be next day):

```
PARAMETERS
    StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime;
SELECT 
    HealthVault2.Time, HealthVault2.Date_Time
FROM 
    HealthVault2
WHERE IIF(StartTime <= EndTime,
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) >= StartTime
    AND
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) <= EndTime,
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) >= StartTime
    OR
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) <= EndTime);

- or simplified:

WHERE 
    (StartTime <= EndTime)
    XOR
    (TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) >= StartTime
    AND
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) <= EndTime);
```

Comment: Returns even more values out of the intended range. I think it needs parameters specifying the date range (based on the correct observation by Fionnuala)

Comment: Works to a degree but when changed to SELECT HealthVault2.Time, HealthVault2.Date_Time
FROM HealthVault2
WHERE 
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) >= #06:00:00#
    OR
    TimeValue(HealthVault2.Time) <= #10:00:00#; 

returns all values

Comment: Yes, and you should be able to see why. However, see edit.